# SOAP Payload with nested complexType

Tags: soap, soapui

I'm trying to make a SOAP request where a parameter is a complex type, and  I'm having trouble getting the syntax right.

- WSDL: https://www.dayforcehcm.com/DataSvc/DayforceService.svc?singleWsdl
- Action: IDayforceService/Query

Here is the SOAP request that was generated by SoapUI:

```
    <SOAP-ENV:Envelope 
            xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
            xmlns:ns1="http://Dayforce/Services/DayforceService">
        <SOAP-ENV:Body>
            <ns1:Query>
                <ns1:sessionTicket>?</ns1:sessionTicket>
                <ns1:request/>
            </ns1:Query>
        </SOAP-ENV:Body>
    </SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

My question is how to fill in the `<ns1:request/>` element.  The request should be a `GetReportDefinitionsRequest`, and it needs to provide a string value for `XRefCode`.

SoapUI isn't being much help here, and WSDL to class generators I've tried have similar problems.  At this point I'd settle for just knowing the proper XML syntax

Here are the relevant types (also available in the WSDL above).

Query:

```
<xs:element name="Query">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="sessionTicket" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element xmlns:q9="http://Dayforce/Services/Data" minOccurs="0" name="request" nillable="true" type="q9:DFRequest"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

GetReportDefinitionsRequest:

```
<xs:complexType name="GetReportDefinitionsRequest">
    <xs:complexContent mixed="false">
        <xs:extension base="tns:DFRequest">
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="XRefCode" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:extension>
    </xs:complexContent>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:element name="GetReportDefinitionsRequest" nillable="true" type="tns:GetReportDefinitionsRequest"/>
```

DFRequest:

```
<xs:complexType name="DFRequest">
    <xs:complexContent mixed="false">
        <xs:extension base="tns:DFObject">
            <xs:sequence/>
        </xs:extension>
    </xs:complexContent>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:element name="DFRequest" nillable="true" type="tns:DFRequest"/>
```

DFObject:

```
<xs:complexType name="DFObject">
    <xs:sequence/>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:element name="DFObject" nillable="true" type="tns:DFObject"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

I was able to get the sample code running and hook in to get the XML generated for the request.  Here's the result, in case it helps anyone in the future.

The important part is to assign the `type` attribute to the  tag.  That involves importing the `http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance` namespace to get the type attribute, and the `http://Dayforce/Services/Data` namespace for the type itself.

```
    <SOAP-ENV:Envelope 
        xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
        xmlns:dfs="http://Dayforce/Services/DayforceService">
    <SOAP-ENV:Header/>
    <SOAP-ENV:Body>
        <dfs:Query>
            <dfs:sessionTicket>?</dfs:sessionTicket>
            <dfs:request 
                    xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                    xmlns:dfd="http://Dayforce/Services/Data" 
                    i:type="dfd:GetReportDefinitionsRequest">
                <dfd:XRefCode>?</dfd:XRefCode>
            </dfs:request>
        </dfs:Query>
    </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```